# PyCharm: importing cython module that uses dynamic libraries itself - ImportError & Code Completion

Tags: python, cython, importerror

I've got a cython module that is a wrapper around a c++ library that communicates with a database. That library is called `libpersistence.so`. That library itself is dynamically linked with `libhiredis.so`.
I wrote a cython wrapper around the `libpersistence.so` to create a `py_persistence.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` file to import as a module in my python scripts to use the cpp persistence layer.

However, upon importing the py_persistence module there's two issues in PyCharm:

1. Importing the `Persistence` class from the module does not get recognized by PyCharm. This also means there is no code completing
2. Running my tests leads to an ImportError where the libpersistence.so file shared object file can not be opened.

I use the following directory structure.

```
top_level/
    indexing_service/
        bin/
            libhiredis.so.0.13
            libpersistence.so
        kCore/
            include/
                hiredis/
                persistence/

    query_service/
        __init__
        runpython.sh
        py_persistence/
            __init__
            py_persistence.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
            py_persistence.pxd
            py_persistence.pyx
            setup.py
            setup.sh
            test/
                test_persistence.py
```

The `setup.sh` file just specifies `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace`
The `setup.py` file is the following:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext, Extension

setup(
        cmdclass = { 'build_ext' : build_ext },
        ext_modules = [
            Extension(
                'py_persistence',
                sources=['py_persistence.pyx'],
                libraries=['persistence'],
                language='c++',
                extra_link_args=['-L../../indexing_service/bin/'],
                runtime_library_dirs=['../../indexing_service/bin/'],
                extra_compile_args=[
                    '-std=c++14',
                    '-I../../indexing_service/kCore/include/persistence',
                    '-I../../indexing_service/kCore/include/hiredis'
                ],
                cython_directives={
                    'c_string_type':'unicode',
                    'c_string_encoding':'utf8',
                },
            )],
)
```

So when building the cython py_persistence library it links to the both the `libpersistence.so` and the `libhiredis.so.0.13` files for dynamic linking. This works, this compiles and it builds the `py_persistence.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` file correctly.

When I run my tests using the `runpython.py` helper script I wrote everything works perfectly fine. 
The `runpython.py` explicitely adds the required directories to the runtime library path:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:.
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:../indexing_service/bin/:.
python3 ${@:1}
```

Running the tests:
`./runpython.sh -m unittest discover py_persistence/test -v`

This works perfectly.
However getting this setup working so that I can run it from PyCharm is giving me a lot of trouble. I don't seem to be able to correctly specfify the paths. In the `test_persistence.py` file I get an `ImportError` while importing the py_persistence library.

Import code:

```
from py_persistence.py_persistence import Persistence
```

The error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 58, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 600, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 34, in testFailure
    raise self._exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_persistence
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 428, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/tom/work/dev/alexandria.works/query_service/py_persistence/test/test_persistence.py", line 3, in <module>
    from py_persistence.py_persistence import Persistence
ImportError: libpersistence.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've already tried adding the `indexing_service/bin/` folder to the path in PyCharm for the virtual environment:

[Interpreter Paths in PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6MOw.png)

The run configuration used to run the tests is the following:

[Run Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGqcz.jpg)

The problems I'm experiencing are the ImportError and the fact that code completion isn't working. 
I'm at a loss about what else to try here... Printing `sys.path` in the `test_persistence.py` file tells me that the `indexing_service/bin/` folder is on the path.

```
['/home/tom/Applications/pycharm-2017.1.1/helpers/pycharm', 
'/home/tom/work/dev/alexandria.works/query_service/py_persistence/test', 
'/home/tom/work/dev/alexandria.works/indexing_service/bin', 
'/home/tom/work/dev/alexandria.works/query_service', 
'/home/tom/Applications/pycharm-2017.1.1/helpers/pycharm', 
'/home/tom/work/dev/alexandria.works/query_service/dev-env/lib/python35.zip', 
'/home/tom/work/dev/alexandria.works/query_service/dev-env/lib/python3.5', 
'/home/tom/work/dev/alexandria.works/query_service/dev-env/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
'/home/tom/work/dev/alexandria.works/query_service/dev-env/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.5', 
'/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
'/home/tom/work/dev/alexandria.works/query_service/dev-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

Anybody know what I missed?

Comment: Thanks a lot, GhostCat! I'll check it out.